# Новая папка в Unity после обновления

Tags: unity3d

После перехода на новую версию unity при создании проекта создается папка "Packages"(раньше её не было). Нужна она или можно удалять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С новой версии Unity изменили подход в компоновке кода и распространению расширений. В папке packages будут лежать дополнительные пакеты, которые вы установите через специальный Package Manager в самом редакторе. Другими словами - папка нужна)

Comment: А если они мне не нужны? То что? Раньше и без неё было удобно

Comment: @Сергей, они не могут быть "не нужны" в эти пакеты вынесена часть основного кода юнити, которая раньше была зашита прямо в движок